# ChildProcessError: stdout maxBuffer length exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, kubernetes

We have the following code (don't ask me why...even as none-javascript dev it doesn't look pretty to me), which throws error after Kubernetes upgrade:

```
module.exports.getReplicationControllers = async function getReplicationControllers(namespace) {
  const kubeConfig = (await getNamespacesByCluster()).get(namespace);
  if (!kubeConfig) throw new Error(`No clusters contain the namespace ${namespace}`)
  const kubeConfigEscaped = shellEscape([kubeConfig]);

  const namespaceEscaped = shellEscape([namespace]);
  const result = await cpp(`kubectl --kubeconfig ${kubeConfigEscaped} get replicationcontrollers -o json -n ${namespaceEscaped}`);
  console.error(result.stderr);
  /** @type {{items: any[]}} */
  const resultParsed = JSON.parse(result.stdout);
  const serviceNames = resultParsed.items.map((item) => item.metadata.name);
  return serviceNames;
}
```

> ChildProcessError: stdout maxBuffer length exceeded kubectl --kubeconfig /kubeconfig-staging get replicationcontrollers -o json -n xxx (exited with error code ERR_CHILD_PROCESS_STDIO_MAXBUFFER)

What I've tried so far is:

```
  const result = await cpp(`kubectl --kubeconfig ${kubeConfigEscaped} get replicationcontrollers -o=jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}' -n ${namespaceEscaped}`);
  console.error(result.stderr);
  const serviceNames = result.split(' ');
  return serviceNames;
```

Which returns

> TypeError: result.split is not a function

I am not super versed with JavaScript, any help appreciated.

Comment: There is an [official Javascript Kubernetes client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript); can you use that instead of shelling out to `kubectl`?  (It will probably be easier and safer; the very first example on the GitHub page lists pods and it would be straightforward to adapt that to list replication controllers or other object types.)

Answer (score 2):

**Answering the question in general** (rather than getting you to switch to a different tool), for people who have this question and may be using other apps:

> RangeError [ERR_CHILD_PROCESS_STDIO_MAXBUFFER]: stdout maxBuffer length exceeded

**The issue is caused by your command sending a lot of data (more than 1MB) to stdout or stderr.**

Increase the `maxBuffer` option in exec() for [the node docs for process.exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)

```
exec(someCommand, {
  maxBuffer: 5 * 1024 * 1024,
})
```